# Why do we have two delimiters for query parameters?

Tags: web, query-string, rfc3986

We all know there are 2 delimiters for query strings. Which are `?` and `&`. Why wouldn't we use just `?` for both cases? Why do we need `&`
[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) gives description of the standard, but does't provide us with motivation on that subject.

> The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the various URL specifications, you will see that it doesn't set out any syntax for the `<query>` component.  Indeed, the client and server could agree on any syntax for the string subject to the restrictions on allowed / reserved characters.

The `?<name>=<value>&<name>=<value>` syntax that is most commonly used comes from the HTML specification.  Look for the section of the HTML spec (pick any version) that specifies the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoding scheme for form parameters.

Why does the HTML spec not use `&` as the parameter separator?  I think that is because the URL spec says that `?` is *reserved* in the `<query>` part.  (So if HTML used `?` as a separator, it would need to be percent-encoded.)

Why is `?` reserved in the `<query>` part?  Well now we are getting into the history of `http:` hyperlinks before a unified URL specification existed.  Basically, I don't know, but it *could* have been related to the way that early web servers or browsers parsed hyperlinks.